# ping is very slow to start if hostname is provided even though DNS resolution happens quickly

Tags: linux-networking, ping

I have a network of CentOS servers. On some hosts, if I ping a machine by its hostname then it immediate prints the first line of output which shows that it has resolved the hostname to an IP address but it sits there for something like 30 seconds before it starts displaying ping data.

```
$ ping mymachine
PING mymachine.mydomain.com (w.x.y.z) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

If I ping the machine by its IP then there is no such delay.

Dig shows it take just 32 msec for it to resolve the domain name.

If it were a DNS problem I'd expect ping to take a long time showing that first line with the IP address but there's no delay there.

How can I debug this?

Comment: test the time to each nameserver in your /etc/resolv.conf file, with    `time dig mymachine @dnsserverIP`       I wonder if one is slow, and ping is doing sequential searching when dig is taking the first reply to return.

Comment: I've got 4 DNS servers, two from open dns, and two from google. Timing the dig command to my server through each of the DNS servers shows all 4 to be very fast.

Comment: Rule out DNS problems by using `-n`.

Comment: So, there's definitely a DNS problem. If I do "ping -n" then I don't have the delay. Also, if I add an entry for the machine I'm pinging in /etc/hosts then the problem goes away. I still need to understand why name to IP resolution happens quickly but then ping is slow to get past that first line of output. This is not just a ping problem. ssh is very slow and there are other problems that are probably DNS-related.

Comment: Can you please append the output of `grep dns /etc/nsswitch.conf`   to your question?    (skip comments)   Mine is "hosts:      files dns"   and I suspect yours has something else as well.   dig doesn't use this ordering, but ping does.

Comment: hosts:      files dns

Comment: Is there a problem doing a reverse lookup for this IP? (Iirc ping does this)

Answer (score 1):

You can use mtr diagnostic tool.

Mtr(my traceroute) is a command-line network diagnostic tool that 
provides the functionality of both the ping and traceroute commands. The 
mtr runs on the foreground until canceled, updating the response table 
on each pass.

mtr google.com

Specify a limit for the number of pings

mtr -c 10 google.com

Use TCP SYN packets or UDP datagrams
mtr –tcp “domainName/IP”
mtr –udp “domainName/IP”

Give this a try and post back with the errors you have identified and we shall try to resolve it.

Comment: mtr returns "Resolver: Received error response 2. (server failure)"

Comment: The CentOS 6 version of mtr doesn't have options for tcp or udp.

Comment: Install the mtr tool.  Run "yum install mtr" or "apt-get install mtr-tiny" on Linux host. Use WinMTR on Windows
Run "mtr -P <tcp port> -T <destination ip>" to do a live test
Run "mtr -P <tcp port> -T -w  <destination ip>" to generate a report. It sends 10 packets to the host by default, use "-c <packet number>" for more packets
The Loss% column shows the percentage of packet loss at each hop. The Snt column counts the number of packets sent.

Comment: The next four columns Last, Avg, Best, and Wrst are all measurements of latency in milliseconds (e.g. ms). Last is the latency of the last packet sent, Avg is the average latency of all packets, while Best and Wrst display the best (shortest) and worst (longest) round trip time for a packet to this host. In most cases, the average (Avg) column should be the focus of your attention.

Comment: The final column, StDev, provides the standard deviation of the latencies to each host. The higher the standard deviation, the greater the difference is between measurements of latency.

Comment: When analyzing MTR output, you are looking for two things: loss and latency.  Take a real test result (mtr -P 80 -T -w <ip>)